# VB.net Invoke a property change in a control

Tags: vb.net, properties, invoke, invokerequired

Lots of examples of how to invoke methods, but how does one change a simple property?

For demonstration-sake, here's a very simple set of code that should help.  Let's say I need to set the visible property from a child form, and thus, it needs to be invoked:

```
Friend Sub activateItem(ByVal myItem As PictureBox)

    If myItem.InvokeRequired = True Then
        ????
    Else
        myItem.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Just invoke a method here, activateItem.  Trying to optimize it is pointless, Invoke is *expensive*.

Comment: Hans: when I invoke the method directly, I get an "Expression does not produce a value" error.  After changing the sub to a function with Return True at the end, I get "Cannot cast binary to system.delegate"  Any suggestions?  I'm typically an asp.net guy, so dealing with threading is completely new to me.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using VB.Net 2010, you can use a lambda expression:

```
If myItem.InvokeRequired Then
    myItem.Invoke(Sub() myItem.Visible = True)
```

In your particular case, you can also call `myItem.Invoke(myItem.Show)`.

Comment: Using VS2008 at the moment, so the first option isn't a choice.  The second option gives me an error "myItem.Show does not produce a value"

Comment: Try `myItem.Invoke(AddressOf myItem.Show)`  (I haven't done VB in a while)

Comment: @Brad: Or try `myItem.Invoke(New Action(AddressOf myIem.Show))`

Comment: New error there: AddressOf cannot be converted to System.Delegate because System.Delegate is declared MustInhereit and cannot be created.

Comment: I think our posts crossed in the mail.  The second method worked.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Was hoping I would find someone who asked this question which had a good answer. +1